# AUTENTICACIÓN API RESTFUL VB.Net

Tags: json, vb.net, api, autenticación, tokens

Contexto: Tengo una aplicación WebForm VB.Net que consume una API RestFul actualmente todo me funciona. Pero en mi empresa quieren que cambie mi autenticación y que se haga con Json. Me pueden ayudar a convertirlo a Json y que reciba el Token(Solo necesito el token).

- Link de la documentación de la API https://developers.nubox.com/autenticacion

Este es mi código:

```
Public Function Autenticar(ByVal parmUsuario As String, ByVal parmContraseña As String, ByVal parmUrl As String) As String

        Try
            Dim token As String = ""
            Dim Result As String = ""
            Dim URLPost As String = parmUrl
            ' Concateno los parametros como lo solicita la API
            Dim usuCon As String = parmUsuario + ":" + parmContraseña

            'Se codifica a base64
            Dim codificado = EncodeTo64Y(usuCon)
            Dim webClient As New WebClient()

            'Creo la Cabezera
            webClient.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic " + codificado)
            'Ejecuto
            Result = webClient.UploadString(URLPost, "POST")
            'Extraigo el token de la cabezera devuelta por la API
            Dim Cabeceras As WebHeaderCollection = webClient.ResponseHeaders
            token = Cabeceras.Get("Token")
            webClient.Dispose()
            'Retorno el token
            Return token


        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try

    End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Creo que el problema esta en tu función EncodeTo64Y(usuCon) porque probe colocando directo la cadena de base 64 si retorna el token:

```
Public Function Autenticar(ByVal parmUsuario As String, ByVal parmContraseña As String, ByVal parmUrl As String) As String

    Try
        Dim token As String = ""
        Dim Result As String = ""
        Dim URLPost As String = parmUrl
        ' Concateno los parametros como lo solicita la API
        Dim usuCon As String = parmUsuario + ":" + parmContraseña

        'Se codifica a base64
        'Dim codificado = EncodeTo64Y(usuCon)
        Dim codificado As String = "aWM3cFJISjFOUHJkOkZudldRc2VB"
        Dim webClient As New WebClient()

        'Creo la Cabezera
        webClient.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic " + codificado)
        'Ejecuto
        Result = webClient.UploadString(URLPost, "POST")
        'Extraigo el token de la cabezera devuelta por la API
        Dim Cabeceras As WebHeaderCollection = webClient.ResponseHeaders
        token = Cabeceras.Get("Token")
        webClient.Dispose()
        'Retorno el token
        Return token


    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try

End Function
```

Y me retorna el token: 7a7175df-b75d-40f6-9710-70c0f1253284